# Open multiple files in one instance of a custom program

Tags: windows

I have a very simple .exe program that takes (potentially many) arguments with the following syntax :
`MyProgram.exe file1 file2 file3 ... fileN`
Everything works great here. 
I wish I could open multiple files in a row from the file explorer using 'open with' but Windows actually computes

```
MyProgram.exe file1
MyProgram.exe file2
.
.
.
MyProgram.exe fileN
```

Instead of 
`MyProgram.exe file1 file2 file3 ... fileN`

Is there a configuration file or something else that can let the user customize the way Windows opens multiple files? Any help would be highly appreciated.

I use Windows 7 - 32 bit.

Comment: You can register a DropTarget handler which will be given all the files at once.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that worked perfectly.